# Register types from scanning assemblies between autofac and microsoft dependency-injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, autofac

Recently, we stop to use **Autofac**, and start to use **Microsoft** DependencyInjection in our netcore3.1 web and console applications. We still love both of them could accomplish our decoupling design. Just a simple decision to use native **Microsoft** package if it could do the same stuff with 3rd-party packages. Here are the codes we try to migrate, the point is we've been already getting benefits by registering types from **scanning assemblies**, and we hope keep this design to decrease migration cost,

RequiredServices.cs

> Before DI, to prevent registration explosion (yes, we do have 100+ interfaces and services), we don't register each serivices, prefer use scanning assemblies instead.

```cs
public interface IRepository { } 
public interface IUserRepository: IRepository { }
public interface ITodoRepository: IRepository { }
// ...
public interface INum100Repository: IRepository { }

public abstract class RepositoryBase: IRepository { } 
public class UserRepository: RepositoryBase, IUserRepository { } 
public class TodoRepository: RepositoryBase, ITodoRepository { } 
// ...
public class Num100Repository: RepositoryBase, INum100Repository { }
```

ServiceModule.cs

> Old (migrate from): Legacy container builder by Autofac

```cs
protected override void Load(Autofac.ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    base.Load(builder);

    var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().ToList();
    assemblies.SelectMany(x => x.GetReferencedAssemblies())
        .Where(t => false == assemblies.Any(a =>a.FullName == t.FullName))
        .Distinct()
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(x => assemblies.Add(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(x)));
    var scanAssemblies = assemblies.ToArray();    

    // Core DAL services
    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(scanAssemblies)
        .PublicOnly()
        .Where(t => !t.IsInterface)
        .As<IRepository>()
        .AsImplementedInterfaces()
        .InstancePerDependency();
}
```

ServiceCollectionExtension.cs

> New (migration to): IServiceCollection service descriptors by Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection

```cs
public static IServiceCollection RegisterAssemblyTypes<T>(this IServiceCollection services, ServiceLifetime lifetime, List<Func<TypeInfo, bool>> predicates = null)
{
    var scanAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().ToList();
    scanAssemblies.SelectMany(x => x.GetReferencedAssemblies())
        .Where(t => false == scanAssemblies.Any(a => a.FullName == t.FullName))
        .Distinct()
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(x => scanAssemblies.Add(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(x)));

    var interfaces = scanAssemblies
        .SelectMany(o => o.DefinedTypes
            .Where(x => x.IsInterface)
            .Where(x => x != typeof(T))
            .Where(x => typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(x))
        );

    foreach (var @interface in interfaces)
    {
        var types = scanAssemblies
            .SelectMany(o => o.DefinedTypes
                .Where(x => x.IsClass)
                .Where(x => @interface.IsAssignableFrom(x))
            );

        if (predicates?.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (var predict in predicates)
            {
                types = types.Where(predict);
            }
        }

        foreach (var type in types)
        {
            services.TryAdd(new ServiceDescriptor(
                @interface,
                type,
                lifetime)
            );
        }
    }

    return services;
}
```

Startup.cs

> So, finally we could add by just one line in **Startup.cs** to register types from current assemblies.

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Other DI
    // ...

    // Our core DAL services DI
    services.RegisterAssemblyTypes<IRepository>(ServiceLifetime.Transient);
}
```

Does anything else we have to be careful for this migration stuff ? Thanks for any recommendation or documentation.

Comment: Not sure if you have realized - be careful when you register one type as multiple interfaces. When you do this in Autofac, implementation type is activated **once** and could be returned as different service types, whereas for MS DI, implementation could be activated for each service type. This is because `RegisterType` != `Add*`.

Comment: Hi @weichch, do you mind explain more, will they cause in different results ? Both of them seem get correct dependent service if we call `lifecycleScope.Resolve<IUserRepository>()` in Autofac DI or `serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IUserRepository))` in MS DI

Answer (score 1):

What I meant in comment under question is:

Consider you have service types and implementation type:

```
interface IService1 { }
interface IService2 { }

class Service : IService1, IService2
{ }
```

Autofac registration code:

```
var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();

containerBuilder.RegisterType<Service>()
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    // When you use lifetime
    .SingleInstance();

var autofacContainer = containerBuilder.Build();
```

Microsoft Extensions DI registration code (similar to what you got):

```
var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();

serviceCollection.TryAddSingleton<IService1, Service>();
serviceCollection.TryAddSingleton<IService2, Service>();

var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
```

If you resolve service types:

```
// Autofac
var obj1 = autofacContainer.Resolve<IService1>();
var obj2 = autofacContainer.Resolve<IService2>();

// autofacResult = true
var autofacResult = object.ReferenceEquals(obj1, obj2);

// MS DI
var obj3 = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IService1>();
var obj4 = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IService2>();

// serviceProviderResult = false
var serviceProviderResult = object.ReferenceEquals(obj3, obj4);
```

This is because Autofac registers provided type as singleton and as implementation for all service types, whereas MS DI registers the service/implementation type pair as singleton.

Comment: Noted and thanks. To prevent registration explosion (yes, we do have 100+ interfaces and services),  I edited original posting content to describe the scenario we might use. That's why I said we got benefits from scanning assemblies, a little different from what you mentioned.